# remove a record from has_many without deleting from db? (rails 2.3.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it looks like delete & destroy both remove the record from the db when dealing with a has_many. Is there anyway to not do this. In other words I would like to trim a has_mnay collection before passing it to a method but I dont want my changes to persist to the db. In trying it on the console, it seems to delete immediately when I do

```
second_acct = users.accounts[1]
users.accounts.delete(second_acct)
```

My use case would be something like I want to pass only checking accounts down to a method, so I want to remove these accounts from the user.

Comment: To make sure im clear here, I dont want to touch the db, I only want to remove the relationship in memory

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
second_acct = users.accounts[1]
second_acct.update_attribute(:user_id, nil)
```

This should work.

Or this:

```
second_acct.user = nil
second_acct.save
```

Answer (score -2):

How are your association set up?

```
collection.delete(object, …)
    Removes one or more objects from the collection by setting their foreign keys to NULL. Objects will be in addition destroyed if they’re associated with :dependent => :destroy, and deleted if they’re associated with :dependent => :delete_all.
```

So, if you don't want your records to be deleted and only the association to be cleared, remove `:dependent => :destroy` or `:dependent => :delete_all` option.

Comment: I have dependent => :destroy, when I really delete them I want them cleared from the db. In the case above I  dont want to touch the db, just remove them from the collection in memory..